# Update the first element in a list containing range on integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

In a range of list that contains an interval (1-59/4) i want the first element alone to change for ever 3 rows.

```
n = 14
lis_num = []

for x in range(n):
   lis_num.append('need the logic')

output of lis_num should be like below:
1 1-59/4
2 2-59/4
3 3-59/4
4 1-59/4
5 2-59/4
6 3-59/4
7 ..
8 ..
.....
14 ..
```

and so on from 0-13th row

I havent tried anything yet, looking out for an idea on how we can approach this.

Comment: It is not clear what the input and what the expected output are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and the modulo operator, then convert as string and concatenate the fixed part:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 14

out = pd.Series(np.arange(n)%3+1).astype(str)+'-59/4'

# or
out = pd.Series(np.arange(n)%3+1, dtype=str)+'-59/4'
```

Alternatively, using [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) (less efficient, but maybe more versatile if you have arbitrary prefixes):

```
prefixes = ['1', '2', '3']
n = 14

out = pd.Series(np.tile([f'{p}-59/4' for p in prefixes], int(np.ceil(n/3)))[:n])
```

Or with your loop (not recommended if you need an array/Series as output):

```
n = 14
lis_num = []

for x in range(n):
   lis_num.append(f'{x%3+1}-59/4')

out = pd.Series(lis_num)
```

Output:

```
0     1-59/4
1     2-59/4
2     3-59/4
3     1-59/4
4     2-59/4
5     3-59/4
6     1-59/4
7     2-59/4
8     3-59/4
9     1-59/4
10    2-59/4
11    3-59/4
12    1-59/4
13    2-59/4
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension should do it -

```py
n=14
fixed_str="-59/4"
list1 = [f"{i%3+1}{fixed_str}" for i in range(n)]
```

**Output**

```
['1-59/4',
 '2-59/4',
 '3-59/4',
 '1-59/4',
 '2-59/4',
 '3-59/4',
 '1-59/4',
 '2-59/4',
 '3-59/4',
 '1-59/4',
 '2-59/4',
 '3-59/4',
 '1-59/4',
 '2-59/4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 14
lis_num = []

# Initialize a counter to track rows
counter = 1

# Initialize interval
interval = "1-59/4"

# Iterate over the range
for x in range(n):
    # Append the current interval to lis_num
    lis_num.append(f"{counter} {interval}")
    
    # Increment the counter
    counter += 1
    
    # Check if it's time to update the first element
    if counter % 3 == 1:
        # Update the first element of the interval
        interval = "1-59/4"
    elif counter % 3 == 2:
        # Update the second element of the interval
        interval = "2-59/4"
    else:
        # Update the third element of the interval
        interval = "3-59/4"

# Print each element of lis_num on a new line
for item in lis_num:
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
1 1-59/4
2 2-59/4
3 3-59/4
4 1-59/4
5 2-59/4
6 3-59/4
7 1-59/4
8 2-59/4
9 3-59/4
10 1-59/4
11 2-59/4
12 3-59/4
13 1-59/4
14 2-59/4
```